# SQL Query enclosed join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
Animal
-------------------------------
ID      Name      Color     CarID  ShipID


Ship
-----------------------------------
ID       Length      Depth


Car
------------------------------------
ID      Make      Model     PlaneID 



Plane
------------------------------
ID      Country     Wingspan
```

All keys are as expected (PlaneID is fkey to Plane.ID)

I am looking to make the following query to return all Animals where:

```
Animal.ShipID=47
Animal.Car.Plane.Country = Kenya or Iran or Russia
```

So far I have something like:

```
select Animal.* from
Animal left join (
     select * from Car join Plane on Car.PlaneID = Plane.ID) on Animal.carID = Car.ID
where Animal.ShipID = 47
```

This does not work and I have tried several permutations of this, any help appreciated. thanks!

Comment: a sqlfiddle would be very useful

Comment: how about if no country associated?

Comment: you're missing a `country` table

Comment: country isnt a key, its just a varchar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want ShipID = 47 **OR** country in ('Kenya ','Iran ','Russia')

```
select animal.* 
FROM animal 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ship ON animal.ShipID = ship.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN car ON animal.carID = car.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN plane ON car.PlaneID = plane.ID
WHERE animal.ShipID = 47
OR plane.Country in ('Kenya ','Iran ','Russia')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from animal a
join car c on a.carid = c.id
join plane p on c.planed = p.id
where
  a.shipid = 47
  and/or (p.country = 'Kenya' or p.country = 'Iran' or p.country = 'Russia')
```

Not clear if you want shipid=47 **or** or shipid=47 **and**